# .NET Membership Profile consistency before and after user login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, profile, membership

When I enable Profile in my web app, I can store info for registered users and anonymous visitors.

e.g. supposed I have a "What colour do you like" Textbox at WhatColourDoYouLike.cshtml or WhatColourDoYouLike.aspx,

1. now before I login, as an anonymous visitor I put in "Hot Pink" , the info is stored in aspnet_Profile table, cool.
2. after I logged into the website as a registered user, I visit the same page again and put in "Ocean Blue".
3. When I log off and visit this page to check my colour preference now, however, I don't have "Ocean Blue". I come back to "Hot Pink".

Guess what, as I dig into db aspnet_User and aspnet_Profile tables, I found myself having 2 sets of Profiles. One profile for the anonymous me when I log off = "Hot Pink"; Second profile for the registered me when I logged in = "Ocean Blue".

I always had the impression as I registered/signed up/logged in, .NET will know they are the same person and merge the anonymous profile towards the registered user profile. However, it turns out not. Am I doing something wrong? How do I keep the consistency of the profile before and after login?

Comment: When I dig deeper, I realised by enabling anonymous profile my db can easily pile up millions of anonymous entries. Because when their cookies have expired anonymous entries are not automatically deleted by .NET. So, I need to start implementing my valid-visitor-filter, anonymous-visitor-clean-scheduler. So, The whole anonymous profile thing seems to be more trouble than benefits. Please correct me if I am wrong. I suggest to turn off the anonymous profile all together, 1. only registered user can have a profile entry. 2. for anonymous users, set a seperate cookie to track simple preferences.